# Alter header in products page title in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would like to add "SALE!" to the product page title if the product is on sale.

I have looked in the product controller and in the header and product templates but I have not found where do I pass the title value to the template.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked it out!

I had to insert

```
{if isset($meta_title_tag) AND $meta_title_tag}{$meta_title_tag|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}
```

inside the title tag in my theme and then in productController.php, in the initContent() method, add

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array('meta_title_tag' => "Sale!"));
```

if the product is on sale.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in products edit page to set the product as "SALE!".
If youre template is different than default-bootstrap, check if it has the code needed to show it. You can see this in product-list.tpl

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that but I what I am looking for is to show it on the page title tag